# UI issue while viewing the bounties tab when there are no bounties to display

Tags: bug, design

Previously, there was a question with an active bounty, so I visited the "[Bountied](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties)" tab. I guess between the time I clicked on the link and visited the page, the bounty had expired and resulting in an empty list.

When there are no questions, the fluff text has a slight UI issue. There is no left padding or margins, so it's completely flushed to the border. This is occurring on (at least) FF, Edge, and Chrome.

[image: Fluff text flushed left]

It seems like it is missing `text-align:center` CSS to make it clean and easy on the eyes.

[image: Fluff text centered]